# Loop to click button multiple times with React Testing Library and Jest

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have an 'add' button that adds a new input field. The max allowable input fields to add is 5, when max is reached a message appears. But the test has a warning and an error:

> Warning: You seem to have overlapping act() calls, this is not supported. Be sure to await previous act() calls before making a new one.

> Timed out in waitFor.

```
const { user } = await render({...});

await waitFor(async () => {
             ^
    expect((await screen.findByTestId('add-button'))).toHaveTextContent('Add');

    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i += 1) {
        await user.click(await screen.findByTestId('add-button'));
    }
});

expect((await screen.findByTestId('max-message'))).toHaveTextContent('Reached max');
```

This uses React Testing Library and Jest. Am new to RTL. Any idea how to successfully loop and click a button multiple times? Maybe it just needs a longer timeout. What is causing the warning and is it ok to ignore? Thanks for any info.

Comment: Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example, show the code under test.